# How to make bootstraps's "split button" in Qt widgets

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, qt, widget, qwidget

This is probably simple, though I can't find the correct CSS trick to handle this one.

I want to have this kind of button-group (separated with lines, containing a context menu ) in Qt. They must have native look and feel (not like below examples) so the only needed change seems to be removing rounded corners of a `QPushButton` from its right side (for left-most button), left side (for right most button) and both (for buttons in the middle).

[image: Button Group]

[image: And probably a context menu]

Answer (score 0):

Qt does not support this. You can use CSS to style the buttons like in the example, but you can not use natively styled buttons like this.

If you really need this, the only option I see is to write custom controls for this, with customized drawing code for each OS GUI style you want to support.

You could also try to use standard buttons that overlap and use custom code to paint some kind of line over the overlapping region, but I don't think that would be a good solution.